# Visual studio debug two applications in parallel

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rabbitmq, visual-studio-debugging

I have two projects communicating through RabbitMQ and I want to debug them at the same time, but is there a way to say for one project to stop debugging so I can receive the messages from the message queue and then continue?

Comment: Start the vs 2 times?

Comment: I assume the projects are running in separate processes/containers, like microservices.

Comment: If it's in the same solution, you can start multiple projects, and you could also attach your debugger on a running process

Comment: In Visual Studio, right-click your solution, click **Start-up projects**, select **Multiple**, select-and-away-you-go.

Comment: Note that when you pick multiple projects, each project will use the launch profile that was previously selected for that project. (I would really like a way to select the profile on that screen...)